# Maximum for function $(\theta-(\frac{\mu}{p-x})^a)·x$

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

Struggling with finding the maximum for this function:

$$f(x)=\Bigl(\theta-\Bigl(\frac{\mu}{p-x}\Bigr)^a\Bigr)·x$$

where $\theta>0, \mu>0, p>0, \alpha>1$.

Wolfram Alpha gives me the differential but then for some strange reason it can't solve it. I tried a few other free resources, all of them either refuse to solve it or e.g. stop at a certain step.

Here is the shape of the function just for illustration:

[image]

**Edit:** just noticed the question was closed because of lack of context. This comes from economics.

The function is supposed to be used for revenue maximization.  is a price variation for a product and  is a number of buyers willing to pay a given price. It's based on the hypothesis that price tolerance is a function of wealth distribution. You can see Pareto distribution in the formula, flipped and displaced; then it is multiplied by the price () to give the value of revenue. The idea is that you can field-test presumably 3 price points, get the curve and then find your maximum for revenue.

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method!

Comment: What is the interval for $x$? Unrestricted, there is no maximum (or the max is $\infty$) if $x\to p$.

Comment: @mr_e_man The area of interest is $x=(0,p)$ and it looks like the maximum is always here.

Comment: @mr_e_man for this function it is always $-\infty$. As you can see on the graph, for some positive $\theta, \mu, p$ and for $\alpha>1$ there is a clear maximum.

Comment: @mr_e_man $\mu >0$, so if $x$ tends to $p$, the function tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: Further, $f(0)=0$ and using the calculation in my answer there is some $0 < y < p - \frac{\mu}{\theta^{1/a}}$ s.t. $f(y)>0$ if the interval isn't empty ...

Answer (score 1):

If I did not miscalculate ...
Edit: of course I did :) thanks @mr_e_man

$$f'(x)  = \Bigl(\theta-\Bigl(\frac{\mu}{p-x}\Bigr)^a\Bigr) + xa\Bigl(\frac{\mu}{p-x}\Bigr)^{a+1} (-1/\mu)
= \theta - \Bigl(\frac{\mu}{p-x}\Bigr)^a \Bigl(1+\frac{xa}{p-x}\Bigr)$$

Comment: I think you did miscalculate. I have $$f'(x) = \bigg(\theta-\Big(\frac\mu{p-x}\Big)^a\bigg) + x\bigg(0-(-a)\Big(\frac{p-x}\mu\Big)^{-a-1}(-1/\mu)\bigg)$$